# How to display table on WF Form from MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I have been working on an application that get me experiences on C# coding. Now, I am creating registering new employee form. Saving new employee data to MS SQL is fine now. I want to display those data in the table. I used datagridview, but I am not sure if I still need coding or I just follow the step through datagridview drop-down taks menu. I attempted both ways and none of them worked.  Following Datgridview Task also didin't work and I couldn't connect to SQL server. I am not sure where I went wrong. Here is coding, please help me check what I went wrong. Error was "Incorrect Syntax near the keywork 'Database'. What Database is referred to ?

```
private void DisplayTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strConnectionString = @"Data Source = KK\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security = SSPI; Initial Catalog = JeanDB";

    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    cn.Open();
    string Query = ("Select * from Database.JeanDB");
    SqlCommand DisplayTableData = new SqlCommand(Query, cn);

    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = DisplayTableData;
        DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dbdataset);
        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

        bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
        sda.Update(dbdataset);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the table that you are selecting from?

Comment: I am selecting data from table name dbo.Employees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to this:

```
select * from dbo.Employees
```

This will retrieve data from your desired table. Right now you are using the word database in your query, which is incorrect.

When you set `InitialCatalog` in connection string, the query will try to find the tables in the specified database. If you want to use a specific database on the same server instead of the one in the connection string, you need to change the query to this:

```
select * from [OtherDBName].dbo.Employees
```

Comment: Thank alot for your help. It works now. Now, can you help me explain how to use DataTable, and BindingSource and what they are for. Or you have any links that can explain in easy language. I am a very new in programming.

Comment: You could take a look at this to get started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.90).aspx. If you are stuck, try searching MSDN documentation for the classes/methods that you are having a hard time understanding, since usually it gives a good idea. Also, please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it helped :)